# is it possible to design UI for iOS in html but running logic in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im new to iPhone development. I come from web-development/design and what bothers me in iPhone development is the unability for custom design... In other words... is there any way I could design my user interface (my view) with webkit so all my UI elemnts would be writen in html/css and logic in objective-c. I was thinking if there is a way I could triger some objective-c code when html button is pressed. Is there any way to do that (lets say via "localhost request" or I dont know) ?

BUT not with phonegap or similar, because then you just start writing your logic in javascript and i dont want that... I want my controller and model to be written in objective-c just the view module in html!

Comment: It is certainly possible to do custom design for the iPhone. If you are going to write the logic in Objective-C then I suggest doing everyhing natively. You'll get much better performance and you will not waste time trying to bridge between HTML and Objective-c.

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve? JavaScript is the mechanism that connects your HTML elements to your native code -- why is that a problem? And what's your reason for specifying the UI in HTML in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other responders are correct in that efficiency is a big concern, as all of your logic is gated on the Web/native interface. The UIWebView performs a LOT of it's duties on a single thread, and any of your interactions with it must as well.

If you really want to do this, however, there are solutions... Intercepting events from the UIWebView via delegate methods (such as shouldStartLoadWithRequest) that follow a protocol that you define can be used, but I'd suggest either doing everything in JS (trust me, it will actually be faster), or just bite the bullet and learn native iOS development more.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). It has all of the abilities you specify, and can work on Android and other's too (of course you'd need to write the native logic in Java and other languages for that to work though).

Comment: yes thanks for that... i already saw phonegap but you then start to develop your logic in javascript and i dont want that

Comment: @gr33x93-any particular reason you don't want that?

Comment: @gr33x93: You don't have to. It let's you use native extensions that would let you write the code in Obj-C and just invoke it from JS.